# multiple countdowns starting at oncewith no end

Tags: android, countdown

**First Problem:** 
I have 4 Countdowns(which start from different values) that should start when i click on the imageview next to them. But the problem is, when i click the first picture, all 4 countdowns start; when i click the second picture, the second, third and fourth countdowns start and so on.
I think I've done something wrong in my switch case but it doesn't show any errors and I can't find the mistake.

**Second Problem:**
When i click the "new game" button, all timers should stop and become 0 but when i click the timers start again and show their old remaining time and the new remaining time.
**Code:**

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private Button button_new_fight;
public TextView textviewRed;
public TextView textviewBlue;
public TextView textviewDragon;
public TextView textviewBaron;
public TextView tv;
public ImageView imageviewRed;
public ImageView imageviewBlue;
public ImageView imageviewDragon;
public ImageView imageviewBaron;
private boolean timerRedStarted;
private boolean timerBlueStarted;
private boolean timerDragonStarted;
private boolean timerBaronStarted;
private final long startTimeRed = 300000;
private final long startTimeBlue = 300000;
private final long startTimeDragon = 360000;
private final long startTimeBaron = 420000;
private final long interval = 1000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer_layout);
    //binding content to these attributes to work with them
    button_new_fight = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button_new_fight.setOnClickListener(this);
    textviewRed = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewRedTime);
    textviewBlue = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewBlueTimeLeft);
    textviewDragon = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDragonTimeLeft);
    textviewBaron = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewBaronTimeLeft);

    //binding this.imageviews to those of timer_layout.xml
    imageviewRed = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageviewRed.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageviewBlue = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageviewBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageviewDragon = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageviewDragon.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageviewBaron = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageviewBaron.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // clear all timers
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }
        // start timer red
    case R.id.imageView1:
        if (timerRedStarted == false) {
            countDownTimer = new MyCount(startTimeRed, interval,
                    textviewRed);
            textviewRed.setText(textviewRed.getText()
                    + String.valueOf(startTimeRed));
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
        // start timer blue
    case R.id.imageView2:
        if (timerBlueStarted == false) {
            countDownTimer = new MyCount(startTimeBlue, interval,
                    textviewBlue);
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
        // start timer dragon
    case R.id.imageView3:
        if (timerDragonStarted == false) {
            countDownTimer = new MyCount(startTimeDragon, interval,
                    textviewDragon);
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
        // start timer baron
    case R.id.imageView4:
        if (timerBaronStarted == false) {
            countDownTimer = new MyCount(startTimeBaron, interval,
                    textviewBaron);
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

}

class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

```
private TextView tv;

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, TextView tv) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.tv = tv;
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    tv.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First Problem: 
>   I have 4 Countdowns(which start from different values) that should start when i click on the imageview next to them. But the problem is, when i click the first picture, all 4 countdowns start; when i click the second picture, the second, third and fourth countdowns start and so on.
>   I think I've done something wrong in my switch case but it doesn't show any errors and I can't find the mistake.

You need to put `break;` statements in your `switch/case` or everything will get ran

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
    // clear all timers
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer = null;
    }
    // start timer red
break;                  // <-- break statements
case R.id.imageView1:
    if (timerRedStarted == false) {
        countDownTimer = new MyCount(startTimeRed, interval,
                textviewRed);
        textviewRed.setText(textviewRed.getText()
                + String.valueOf(startTimeRed));
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
    // start timer blue
break;
case R.id.imageView2:
    if (timerBlueStarted == false) {
        countDownTimer = new MyCount(startTimeBlue, interval,
                textviewBlue);
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
break;
```

> Second Problem:
>   When i click the "new game" button, all timers should stop and become 0 but when i click the timers start again and show their old remaining time and the new remaining time.

Fixing your first problem may fix this problem as well. Also, you may need to reinitialize your timer variables

Comment: the first problem is solved but it didn't fix the second one.. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your second problem exactly the same? It shouldn't be, assuming `R.id.button1:` is your "new game button". Have you reinitialized your start times?

Comment: Yet I only added the breaks, how do I reinitialize the start times?
Is there a way to get all initialized CountDownTimer's ?

Comment: I may have been thinking of it wrong. You added `break` for the `Button` `case` also, right?

Comment: Yes I did, you wrote that above too. Shouldn't I?

Comment: Yes you should. I was just verifying because without running the code I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: I tried again and now only the last timer that i started is cancelled by clicking the button, the others keep running.

Comment: You should probably be using different timer variables. ex... cdRed, cdBlue`, etc...Declare all of them as class variables then initialize them when needed since you have multiple timers running at the same time